# FFmpeg disassemble video into parts

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg

How can I disassemble a video into parts with given timecodes, so far I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i test.m2v -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:01:12 -t 00:04:21 -sn part1.m2v
```

But somehow the video has a length of over `6` minutes, whereas it shall have a length of `00:03:09 (00:04:21 - 00:01:12)`.

What am I doing wrong

**Edit:**

If I do the same command with the start time of `00:00:00` like this:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i test.m2v -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:21 -sn part1.m2v
```

It creates me a correct output.

Comment: @Mulvya hi I looked through that post but that did not work

Comment: It won't work - I linked to an explanation for why it won't work. Drop the copy mode for precise duration.

Comment: @Mulvya hmm how would the command look like then?

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i test.m2v -acodec copy -ss 00:01:12 -to 00:04:21 -sn part1.m2v` (`-t` is for duration, not outpoint)

Comment: @Mulvya why does something like this not work:
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i test.m2v -acodec copy -ss 00:02:55 -to 00:00:16 -sn newtest.m2v

Comment: `-t` is for duration; `-to` is for outpoint. 2m55s to 0m16s isn't valid.

Comment: @Mulvya ty that worked would you like to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -t for duration; and -to for outpoint

So use

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i test.m2v -acodec copy -ss 00:01:12 -to 00:04:21 -sn part1.m2v
```